# mptt tree pagination

Tags: django, django-mptt

I want to make simple pagination of mpttmodel instances. I have this model:

```
class Thing(MPTTModel):
    text = models.TextField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

The problem is, when i trying to retrive objects with offset, like:

```
Thing.objects.all()[5:10]
```

`{% recursetree things %}` template tag raises exception: `Caught AssertionError while rendering: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.`

How to solve it?

Comment: Did you try  list(Thing.objects.all())[5:10]  - that might work, since Django has to fetch all data before slicing. Your original call uses a LIMIT and OFFSET clause in your SQL.You might do that in a python shell and see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The [`recursetree`](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/master/mptt/templatetags/mptt_tags.py#L290) tag needs a queryset passed to it that doesn't have the array-slicing limit syntax applied to it.

You can either use the [model and manager instances](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/models.html) to construct a more suitable queryset or call `recursetree` and traverse the nodes, filter them out and call `recursetree` from therein with the selected nodes again if you need to, but that's a bit more convoluted.

Right now, looks like you could achieve what you want with:

```
nodes = [node.get_descendants(include_self=True) 
         for node in Thing.objects.all()[5:10]]
```

And in the template:

```
{% for node in nodes %}
    {% recursetree node %}...{% endrecursetree %}
{% endfor %}
```